# Understanding Unnamed Column in SQL Select Statement Results

Tags: sql, sybase

I am more familiar with a MongoDB architecture than sql. A colleague passed this query to me in order to get some data out of sybase:

```
SELECT order_items.contracted_rate FROM customers
JOIN orders
  ON orders.customers_id = customer.id_number
JOIN order_items
  ON order_items.order_id = orders.id,
ORDER by customer.id_number
```

When I run this query I get data that looks like this:

```
    contracted_rate
1 | 20
2 | 14
3 | 18
```

My question is, what are the left-side numbers pertaining to from the above query? In other words, how can I map these item numbers (1, 2, 3) to a sybase table?

I'm used to seeing something more like this after running a sybase query:

```
id  contracted_rate
1 | 20
2 | 14
3 | 18
```

So I'm trying to understand what the unnamed column refers to, and how I can map it to a sybase table to match up the correct customers?

Comment: The select is not selecting a customerID, that just looks like a row ID, you need to add customerID to your select statement

Comment: Thanks, @Brad. Do you mean customer.id_number? And where would that go in the statement?

Comment: As you are only selecting one column (the contracted_rate), it seems like the tool you are using simply numbers the rows it's showing. A mere display thing which has nothing to do with data.

Comment: Pretty sure that's just a column in the GUI for readability, it's not actually part of the result set. If you want an ID you need to define one.

Comment: So how would I get the result set then?

Comment: Tell the DBMS what you want to select. So far it's just that contracted_rate column. If you want to see more (and you should; don't you want to know *which* order and *which* customer and *which* item?), then select those columns.

Comment: @Muirik Depends. Do you want the customer_id or do you just want some integer that uniquely identifies the row?

Comment: I definitely want the customer_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the customerID you need, you can do this.  The Id you show is not part of the result set

```
SELECT customer.id_number, order_items.contracted_rate
FROM customers
JOIN orders
  ON orders.customers_id = customer.id_number
JOIN order_items
  ON order_items.order_id = orders.id,
ORDER by customer.id_number
```

Comment: So if I end up with id_numbers with multiple results in my result set (i.e. several rows showing the same id_number), this means there are multiple contracted_rate(s) per id_number?

Comment: Yes that would be the case.  Since I dont know the data structure/dependencies, you could even get more then one of the same ID and contracted_rate if the database holds that information that way, (which it looks like it could because a customer may have multiple different orders but with the same contract rate (since you are not using order ID anywhere just customerID that may be possible, but im just going off the table names so I cant be certain)